# Cubic polynomial with $\cos\frac{\pi}{18}$ as a root.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

Find a cubic polynomial with integer coefficients such that $\cos\dfrac{\pi}{18}$ is one of is roots.

---

I tried using roots of unity to solve this, but it didn't quite work, and I'm not sure how else to do this.

Comment: $\cos(3x)=\ldots$

Comment: $\cos(3x)=4\cos^3 x- 3\cos x$ but how does that help?

Comment: @MathMagician That gives you a cubic, but it won't have integer coefficients. You'll need a sextic for that.

Comment: Yes the problem is wrong. You need either $\cos^2(\pi/18)$ or $\cos(\pi/9)$ if you want a cubic with integer coefficients.

Comment: @dxiv: I assume that the sextic you got is $64x^6 - 96x^4 + 36x^2 - 3 = 0$.

Comment: @Dan Right, that's $\;4 \cdot \left( (4 x^3 - 3 x)^2 - \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2\right)\,$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By De Moivre's Formula,

$$(\cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta))^3 = \cos(3\theta) + i \sin(3\theta)$$

Let $\theta = \frac{\pi}{18}$.  Then,

$$\left(\cos(\frac{\pi}{18}) + i \sin(\frac{\pi}{18})\right)^3 = \cos(\frac{\pi}{6}) + i \sin(\frac{\pi}{6})$$
$$\left(x + i \sin(\frac{\pi}{18})\right)^3 = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + i \frac{1}{2}$$

Now, you just need to figure out a way to get $\sin(\frac{\pi}{18})$ out of the picture, and you'll have an equation for $x = \cos(\frac{\pi}{18})$.